# Building an SSIS 2014 Solution from the CMD line throws error: Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load

Tags: ssis

I have a CI process that worked fine on SSIS 2012, but when upgrading these projects to 2014, I ran into some issues.  I am running the following cmd:

devenv.com MySsisProjects.sln /Build "Release"

I get the following error reported:

devenv.com : 
At line:15 char:9
+         & $devenv $Sln_to_Build.FullName /Build "Release"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.31101.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Package 'TestWindowPackage' failed to load.
1>------ Build started: Project: ProjectName1, Configuration: Development ------
2>------ Build started: Project: ProjectName2, Configuration: Development ------
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

So there are a couple of issues:

- There is the weird error that is thrown
- The projects do get built, but in the development configuration
- There is a test project also in this solution which is not getting built at all

All of these things build fine in the IDE.
I'm thinking this is a bug, does anyone have any suggestions of things to try before I put a connect item in for it?

m

Comment: Did you find out why any of that happened because I'm seeing the same errors and there is no answer here?

Comment: I think I wound up using devenv.exe. It was one of those things where I didn't have the time to focus on it, so I got it to work and moved on

Comment: fair enough. thanks for replying anyway